# django 1.6 serving static files

Tags: django, apache, hosting

I am trying to launch a django site on apache/centos 6 and serve the content using apache on the server

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/etzsales/public_html/detectphonenumbers/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://sailstree.com/static/'
```

I have static in installed apps as well.

Yet I get 404 for all the images,css, js

I am able to collect static from my static folder and its now in STATIC_ROOT folder

In my html page I have for example base.html

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
```

Notice I tried static tag as well as static_url settings

All I get is a 404 and if I open the link it says

The requested url is not found

Is apache actually serving my static or am I missing anything

My apache is a big mess I can post it if you need them, but these are the most important

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/etzsales/public_html/detectphonenumbers/detectphonenumbers/wsgi.py
<VirtualHost 50.62.213.44:80>
    ServerName www.ip-50-62-213-44.ip.secureserver.net
    ServerAlias www.ip-50-62-213-44.ip.secureserver.net
    # Alias /robots.txt /var/www/django/mysite/static/robots.txt
    # Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/django/mysite/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/admin/ /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/etzsales/public_html/detectphonenumbers/static/
    Alias /media/ /home/etzsales/public_html/detectphonenumbers/media/

    <Directory /home/etzsales/public_html/detectphonenumbers/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/etzsales/public_html/detectphonenumbers/media/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/etzsales/public_html/detectphonenumbers/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Somebody please help me as I am fighting with this for the past 2 days
Thanks everybody,

Also if the information provided is not sufficient, please let me know I will post the full apache httpd.conf

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think your config is conflicting. You're trying to serve static files through django, yet I also see aliases for these directories in your apache config.